# How to count the number of rows corresponding to a list of times in SQL table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to query from a SQL table. The table name is `my_table` and there's a datetime column `dt` with format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

I would like to count the number of rows for each half hour beginning at 8AM until 6PM.

So currently, I manually do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE dt = '2023-05-08 08:00:00'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE dt = '2023-05-08 08:30:00'
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE dt = '2023-05-08 09:00:00'
...
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE dt = '2023-05-08 18:00:00'
```

I'm new to SQL, and I was thinking of just looking up how to do a for loop and do the above in a loop, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way?

Comment: DateTime columns don't have a "format": their actual internal representation in databases is typically an integer number similar in concept to Unix timestamps

Comment: _"of just looking up how to do a for loop and do the above"_ - fun fact: SQL doesn't have loops nor control-structures, this is because SQL is not a general-purpose  nor Turing-Complete programming language: instead it's a (horribly mutated) representation of a relational-calculus.

Comment: What DBMS you are using? could you share a sample of your input table and the expected output?

Comment: Please tell us exactly what RDBMS you're using, because some (i.e. the good ones) have features for making these kinds of queries easier, e.g. doing a `JOIN` with `GENERATE_SERIES()` - but we don't want to waste your time with things that won't work on your system.

Comment: Assuming your `dt` values are actually the specific 30 minute timestamps you're looking for, the simplest way is to `select dt, count(*) from my_table group by dt`

Comment: @Kurt Needs an `ORDER BY`  too - otherwise the dates will be out-of-order.

Comment: Why are values from '2023-05-08 08:10:23' unimportant?

Comment: It is dependent on your dbms to choose the functions to use. Basically, you would select dt, count(*) grouping by dt and filtering on dt checking if it is within a specific period (ie: between '2023-05-08 08:00:00' and '2023-05-08 18:00:00' and minute part is in 0, 30. Or you might in fact after half hour 'buckets'.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? There are system functions or window functions depending on what you are using that will help solve this. Are you looking for counts within 30 min intervals? It seems you are asking that but your current "manual" code has clauses picking exact times.